# Mimicking HTACCESS rewrite on IIS server

Tags: php, .htaccess, iis

I have a php api and it was hosted on a linux server - i was using this htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine On

#RewriteBase /api/

Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
```

But now i'm moving to IIS i cannot access the routes of the index.php (index.php/login) by using url/api/login. I have to write url/api/index.php/login.

This is what i have set up on iis's URL Rewrite :

[image]

Comment: You could try the "Import Rules" option in the right-side menu of the URL Rewrite module. You can directly refer to your .htaccess file or copy and paste the rules in to the Rewrite rules box.

Comment: Also, to match your "is not a file" condition, you can use the "Conditions" area shown in the image you posted. To match your "L" flag you can check the "Stop processing..." checkbox.